mimic photos app collectionview spacing when not scrolling
Please use this gif as reference for expected result
Work is in progress and public in this github
I'm using default UICollectionViewFlowLayout and set custom sizing for the selected cell when scrolling is not in motion. What can I do to mimic the additional spacing between the selected cell and its neighbours?
If I understand correctly, to have different spacing between cells, I'll have to write custom subclass of UICollectionViewLayout. however, this spacing is related to scrolling behaviour, and with those mixed together, I'm clueless about how to write the implementation. Some code from the public github i'm working on:
private func setupCollectionView() {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = itemSpacing

    let sideInset = (view.bounds.width - 44) / 2 // Ensure first and last items center-align
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: sideInset, bottom: 0, right: sideInset)
    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
// ...
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    if indexPath == collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first {
        if !isScrollingInMotion {
            return .init(width: 44, height: 44)
        }
    }

    return .init(width: 32, height: 44)
}


here I'm using isScrollingInMotion to check if the collectionView is scrolling. it will becomes true when scrollViewDidScroll is called, and becomes false when scrollViewDidEndDecelerating or scrollViewDidEndDragging is called. it also track if the scroll is from user panGesture or from another reason (e.g. select the item directly caused the scrollview to center the cell)

My guess is that you're barking up the wrong tree. I haven't tried to imitate the Photos interface, but my guess is: (1) You're not going to accomplish this with a mere "default UICollectionViewFlowLayout"; you need to write a custom layout. Search for "carousel" for some ideas to get you started. (2) The difference between the while-scrolling and at-rest layouts is probably expressed by two completely different layouts, not some layout that somehow tries to modify itself as you are trying to do.

@matt thanks for your replied. as for (1), I've already considered it in the question, just not clear if it is or not. as for (2), are you suggesting using 2 different layout objects for these 2 states while-scrolling and at-rest? e.g. when scrolling, use a layout object and while at rest, change to a different layout object? that'd be interesting as I never thought I could do that.

The ability to change from one layout to another is one of collection view's best features. When you change from one to another you automatically get a lovely animation as the items move into their new sizes/positions — which is exactly what we see happening in the Photos app.

Thanks to the suggestion from @matt, I've managed to increase the spacing as expected, using 2 different layouts for 2 different states: scrolling and static.
private var isScrollingInMotion = false { didSet {
    guard isScrollingInMotion != oldValue else { return }

    if isScrollingInMotion {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = photoViewerScrollingLayout
    } else {
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = photoViewerStaticLayout
    }
}}

private let photoViewerScrollingLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
private lazy var photoViewerStaticLayout = PhotoViewerCollectionViewLayout(scrollingLayout: photoViewerScrollingLayout)

private func setupCollectionView() {
    photoViewerScrollingLayout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    photoViewerScrollingLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = itemSpacing

    let sideInset = (view.bounds.width - 44) / 2 // Ensure first and last items center-align
    photoViewerScrollingLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: sideInset, bottom: 0, right: sideInset)

    collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: photoViewerStaticLayout)

my layout attribute:
/// use when scrolling is not in motion
final class PhotoViewerCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    init(scrollingLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout) {
        super.init()
        scrollDirection = scrollingLayout.scrollDirection
        minimumInteritemSpacing = scrollingLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing
        sectionInset = scrollingLayout.sectionInset
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return attributes }
        guard let selectedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return attributes }

        let updatedAttributes = attributes.map { $0.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes }
        let itemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing + 5

        for attribute in updatedAttributes {
            if attribute.indexPath.item > selectedIndexPath.item {
                // Custom item on the right
                attribute.frame.origin.x += itemSpacing

            } else if attribute.indexPath.item == selectedIndexPath.item {
                attribute.size.width = attribute.size.height
            } else {
                // Custom item on the left
                attribute.frame.origin.x -= itemSpacing
            }
        }

        return updatedAttributes
    }
}

the animation looks fine (a little clutched but acceptable)
private func snapSelectedCenter() {
    guard !isUserScrolling else { return }
    guard let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return }
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        if !self.isScrollingInMotion {
            self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
        }

        self.isScrollingInMotion = false
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    } completion: { _ in
        self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    isUserScrolling = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2) {
        self.isScrollingInMotion = true
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.invalidateLayout()
    }
}

Now, there's only an issue with the default minimumInteritemSpacing:
if itemSpacing: CGFloat is not 8, (e.g. 0), when I'm scrolling (userBeginDragging), the spacing suddenly being set to a default value (8) instead of my preset number (e.g. 0). Maybe I should subclass even more? I'm not sure...
EDIT
I've found the reason for the weird spacing: the collection used the minimumLineSpacing instead of expecting minimumInteritemSpacing. I've changed to use only 1 layout for both states, custom the spacing (minimumLineSpacing and minimumInteritemSpacing) to fit my needs.
now it's pretty smooth, working as expected. I've updated public git repo if anyone want to see the final solution.
Note: it will break when changing orientation, but I don't plan to fix that.
